# What library to use for Azure Table Storage on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-table-storage

I'm looking to pull some data from azure table storage into a windows phone 8 app. I'm a huge newbie on this but it seems like the Phone.Storage library is outdated and attempting to use

```
nuget install-package windowsazure.Storage
```

gets me an error that System.Spatial 5.2.0 has no windows phone 8 version. I don't actually care about the spatial data types and would be pretty happy with just the ability to get back a POCO item from table storage. I suppose I could do it using the REST API but I was hoping there might be a friendly library to help me out with creating the query and re-hydrating my objects.

Comment: What language is your app written in? There are examples for the convenience APIs that someone could point you to.

Comment: I'm writing this in C#.

Comment: wubdiwsazue.storage doesn't work with WP. What do you mean phone.storage is outdated? can you not use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stimms,

Open the package manager console and type:
Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage-Preview -Pre

The library is still preview for win8 and WP8.